# Blue screen in a-frame

Tags: socket.io, aframe

I am using A-frame and multi user experience we are using socket.io. But when I open the application I am getting a blue loading screen which restricts the view.

Can someone suggest how do we solve this problem. I have attached a image for this.
[Blue screen in a-frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LAkQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give loading-screen="enabled:false" in a-scene